# Asterisk channel usage history

Tags: statistics, command-line-interface, asterisk

i have installation of asterisk 13 with few SIP channels and try figure out how to get history of channel usage or statistic from last day, week, etc.
It is possible using CLI?

Comment: You can get this info via SNMP if you want (it will log all sorts till a restart). Not sure about other methods tho myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup CDR to log every connection to file or to database. Then you can do any statistical analysis you need with this data.